# SQLite Group and Sort By Work Shift

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, date, datetime

I have a query that needs to perform a running sum based 
on date/time and shift.

The shifts are 6:00am to 4:30pm 
and 6:00pm to 4:30 am.

The query engine im using is SQLite.

I am having trouble with the following SQL query. Below you will see the query 
and the current results, followed by the desired results.
The current results are not correctly order by date/time/shift
causing the total QTY column to also display incorrect data.

Is there anyone who has run into this issue before and can possibly
nudge me in the correct direction. I am open to suggestions
even if I have to sort the data without a query, preferably using
java.

```sql
SELECT tdate, qty, shift,
       ( 
           SELECT sum( b.qty )
           FROM table1 AS b
           WHERE (   
                     ( 
                        ( b.id <= a.id AND b.shift = a.shift)
                     )  
                 ) 
            GROUP BY date(b.tdate)
       ) 
       AS bo_total
FROM table1 AS a
ORDER BY date( a.tdate ) ASC, a.shift ASC
```

CURRENT RESULTS

```sql
DATE/TIME             QTY          SHIFT   TOTAL QTY
2014-04-21 07:19:00        60           first        60
2014-04-21 08:45:00        60           first        120
2014-04-21 09:52:00        60           first        180
2014-04-21 13:26:00        60           first        240
2014-04-21 18:51:00        60           second       60
2014-04-21 20:56:00        60           second       120
2014-04-22 06:52:00        60           first        60
2014-04-22 11:56:00        60           first        120
2014-04-22 19:12:00        60           second       60
2014-04-22 20:30:00        60           second       120
2014-04-22 00:50:00        60           second       120
2014-04-23 06:23:00        60           first        60
2014-04-23 09:19:00        60           first        120
2014-04-23 22:11:00        60           second       60
2014-04-23 19:39:00        60           second       120
2014-04-23 00:55:00        60           second       120
2014-04-24 06:59:00        60           first        60
2014-04-24 07:40:00        60           first        120
2014-04-24 16:03:00        60           first        240
2014-04-24 00:42:00        60           second       60
2014-04-24 20:25:00        60           second       120
2014-04-24 00:39:00        60           second       60
2014-04-24 02:32:00        60           second       60
```

DESIRED RESULTS

```sql
DATE/TIME              QTY            SHIFT   TOTAL QTY
2014-04-21 07:19:00        60           first        60
2014-04-21 08:45:00        60           first        120
2014-04-21 09:52:00        60           first        180
2014-04-21 13:26:00        60           first        240
2014-04-21 18:51:00        60           second       60
2014-04-21 20:56:00        60           second       120
2014-04-22 00:50:00        60           second       180
2014-04-22 06:52:00        60           first        60
2014-04-22 11:56:00        60           first        120
2014-04-22 19:12:00        60           second       60
2014-04-22 20:30:00        60           second       120
2014-04-23 00:55:00        60           second       180
2014-04-23 06:23:00        60           first        60
2014-04-23 09:19:00        60           first        120
2014-04-23 19:39:00        60           second       60
2014-04-23 22:11:00        60           second       120
2014-04-24 00:39:00        60           second       180
2014-04-24 00:42:00        60           second       240
2014-04-24 02:32:00        60           second       300
2014-04-24 06:59:00        60           first        60
2014-04-24 07:40:00        60           first        120
2014-04-24 16:03:00        60           first        180
2014-04-24 20:25:00        60           second       60
```

Sample Scheme

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1 ( 
    ID         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    qty        STRING,
    tdate      STRING,
    shift      STRING 
);

INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-16 08:38:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-16 00:15:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-16 15:48:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-16 19:46:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-16 21:44:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-17 00:25:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-17 03:45:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-15 06:02:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-15 08:40:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-15 11:05:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-15 13:48:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'6','2014-05-15 16:08:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-15 19:08:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-15 21:26:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-16 01:16:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-16 04:09:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-14 05:49:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-14 09:58:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-14 13:33:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-14 18:53:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-15 00:09:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-15 02:50:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-13 06:32:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-13 09:19:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-13 00:13:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-13 13:15:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-13 18:28:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-13 21:04:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-13 22:26:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-14 00:44:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-14 02:35:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-12 06:20:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-12 07:12:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-12 09:25:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-12 00:01:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-12 14:51:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-12 19:11:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-12 21:19:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-13 00:07:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-13 02:17:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-10 08:15:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-10 09:36:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-10 09:37:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-10 11:59:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-10 14:44:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-10 19:17:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'13','2014-05-10 21:43:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'58','2014-05-10 21:43:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-11 00:30:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-11 02:41:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-09 06:12:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-09 09:07:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-09 11:57:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-09 14:20:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-09 18:41:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-09 21:03:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-09 23:56:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-10 01:43:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-10 03:28:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-10 04:19:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-08 06:04:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-08 09:17:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-08 11:12:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-08 20:16:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-08 21:24:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-09 00:03:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-09 01:53:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-07 06:13:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-07 07:34:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-07 09:25:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-07 00:45:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-07 20:19:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-07 21:50:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-08 00:11:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-08 02:33:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-06 06:09:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-06 07:42:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-06 09:12:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-06 00:43:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-06 18:47:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-06 21:09:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-06 23:14:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'50','2014-05-06 23:16:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'61','2014-05-06 23:16:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-07 00:20:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-07 02:09:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-05 06:45:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-05 08:12:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-05 10:27:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-05 14:32:00','first');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-05 19:46:00','second');
INSERT Into Table1 values(NULL,'60','2014-05-05 22:18:00','second');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query first computes the date at which the shift began, which makes the shift comparison easier:

```sql
WITH a AS
(SELECT ID,
        qty,
        tdate,
        shift,
        CASE
          WHEN time(tdate) BETWEEN '05:30' AND '17:00'
                                       THEN date(tdate)           || ' first'
          WHEN time(tdate) >= '17:30'  THEN date(tdate)           || ' second'
          WHEN time(tdate) <= '05:00'  THEN date(tdate, '-1 day') || ' second'
        END AS ShiftID
 FROM Table1)
SELECT tdate,
       qty,
       shift,
       (SELECT sum(qty)
        FROM a AS b
        WHERE b.ShiftID = a.ShiftID
          AND b.tdate  <= a.tdate
       ) AS bo_total
FROM a
ORDER BY tdate
```

If your SQLite driver is older than 3.8.3, use a view instead of the CTE.

Comment: This worked and even correctly grouped a bad date that I noticed that I inserted and categorized as second shift. However I now need to upgrade my JDBC SQLite driver to 3.8.3. I was using 3.7 and the query gives an error near WITH. Is there a way to do this without using a WITH statement? I tried to create a view with out the WITH CTE statement and ended up with more syntax errors.

Comment: `CREATE VIEW a AS SELECT ID ...;`

Comment: Thank you. I just had to make a slight modifaction and create a second view out the bottom portion then all I had to do was select * from c

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want by subtracting 5 hours from the time and using that as the date for comparison.  That way, 4:00 a.m. will be in the same "day" as 11 p.m. of the date before.  I think the following does this in SQLite:

```
SELECT tdate, qty, shift,
       (SELECT sum( b.qty )
        FROM table1 AS b
        WHERE b.id <= a.id AND b.shift = a.shift and
              date(b.tdate, '-5 Hours') = date(a.tdate, '-5 Hours')
       ) 
       AS bo_total
FROM table1 AS a
ORDER BY date(a.tdate ) ASC, a.shift ASC;
```

Comment: Closer but the results are still off. I will post the results of this modified query Shortly.

Comment: No didn't work thank you for your help. If there is anything I can do like provide more sample data I can provide that.

Comment: @user3701137 . . . You can put an example up on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Don't know how to share a fiddle but I edited post to expose a sample scheme